# Methods with mutually exclusive arguments

Tags: python, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to create a Class that can be instantiated with mutually exclusive arguments.
E.g. our class takes either a full URL or creates it piece by piece:

```
def url('protocol','hostname','uri','port', 'url')
```

but we don't need 'protocol','hostname','uri','port' if we provided the full 'url'
it can be done with optional arguments and then check for what's not empty but that's really lame:

```
def url('protocol'= None,'hostname' = None,'uri'= None,'port' = None, 'url'= None)
```

also I don't see it as

```
def url(*args)
```

because we will have to create a parser to see what are we being passed.

How do I create methods with mutually exclusive arguments like this?

Comment: What behaviour do you want if the user does not name any arguments, i.e. the user calls `url(some_value)` and `url(some_value_01, some_value_02, some_value_03)`?

Comment: What about using two methods, with the one taking multiple parameters as a proxy for the one taking the full url?

Comment: That'd be bad, you are right. But still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this is in a class is to use class methods to construct the objects from different sets of parameters.

```
class Url:                                                                      
    def __init__(self, full_url):                                               
        self.url = full_url                                                     

    @classmethod                                                               
    def from_url(cls, full_url):                                                     
        return cls(full_url)                                                    

    @classmethod                                                               
    def from_parts(cls, protocol, hostname, uri, port):
        # Join the parameters and construct object                             
        full_url = f"{protocol}://{hostname}:{port}"                            
        return cls(full_url)
```

Usage:

```
my_url = Url.from_url("http://google.com")                                  
my_url = Url.from_parts("https", "google.com", "", "8080")
```

Using this pattern, the purpose of the function is always clear and there is no ambiguity about the arguments being passed and no exclusivity pattern hidden from the caller.

Comment: The only downside with this waythat is I see is that I cannot instantiate a class with the url / parts. Or can I?

Comment: @KateVelasquez if you really need that flexibility, you'll need to either force the user to use keyword arguments, or internally validate whatever the user passes as input. Also consider implementing these methods as class methods (constructors): `MyClass.from_url()`, `MyClass.from_url_parts()`.

Comment: @KateVelasquez Please see my updated answer using static methods to provide alternative constructors for a `Url` class.

Comment: @jfaccioni This is really cool! would it be considered a good practice to run those two in the class constructor? e.g. if url is present from_url() else from_url_parts()?

Comment: As somebody using your interface, I wouldn't find that to be intuitive. The class constructors above would make it clear to the user how they should be used. A constructor taking five parameters, but using just one or four, would be confusing.

Comment: @dspencer Ok, say I have a third method which GETs a page, how do those two fit in then? do I have to do something like try:  from_url() except: from_parts() ?

Comment: Once you have constructed the class using either of those methods, then you would call the `get_page` method on those instances, e.g. `Url.from_url(my_url).get_page()`

Comment: @dspencer kinda pedantic but class methods (i.e. methods decorated with `@classmethod`) are better suited for constructors (from a code maintenance point of view). You'd then have, for example: `def from_url(cls, full_url): return cls(full_url)`. This manner, if the `Url` class ever gets subclassed, the constructor calls the appropriate subclass.

Comment: @jfaccioni Good to know, thanks. After you mentioned it the first time, I was looking into the difference but didn't find a description as succinct as yours - thanks a lot. Updated my answer to follow best practices.